# meds not appearing in FDA CDER or medical device DBs

Tags: usa, openfda, drugs

The meds not appearing in either are as follows:

- [RabAvert](https://www.drugs.com/cdi/rabavert.html)
- [Donnatal](https://www.drugs.com/mtm/donnatal.html)
- [Androxy](https://www.drugs.com/pro/androxy.html)

The search engine I used for the FDA CDER DB is as follows:

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm

The one I used for the medical device DB is as follows:

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRL/rl.cfm

RabAvert is mentioned at https://www.fda.gov/BiologicsBloodVaccines/ucm133705.htm but a downloadable database would be nice. The FDA CDER and the medical device DB's have txt files you can download that correspond to different tables in a DB. Would there per chance be a similar txt file I could download for the biologics  blood / vaccines DB or do I have to do screen scrapping to get that stuff into a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all special cases.

RabAvert is a biologic, so it is be found in the CBER database, not the CDER database or the medical device database.

Donnatal is an unapproved drug that was grandfathered in 1966 and is still on the market (why are unapproved drugs on the market, and what is the FDA doing to get them off? [See our article](https://www.drugpatentwatch.com/blog/unapproved-drugs-opportunities-rapid-approval-market-exclusivity/) ). You'll only find Donnatal in the National Drug Code directory: https://www.fda.gov/Drugs/InformationOnDrugs/ucm142438.htm . RabAvert and Androxy are there too, and you can also get the database file you're looking for :)

Comment: What do you think of RxNorm? Signing up looks like a bit of a PITA with the "_I will provide an annual report_" checkbox at the bottom of the sign up page but there appears to be a copy of it on fda.gov (https://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/ResourcesForYou/Industry/UCM484660.txt). There isn't a description of that files format however..

Comment: We don't use RxNorm, but that flat file is a great find. I generally prefer flat files over an API.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to explore using the APIs at openFDA (https://open.fda.gov/).

I did a quick search of the Drug Product Labeling API and found matching records for Donnatal and for Androxy. Here are the API queries I ran:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:%22Donnatal%22

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:%22Androxy%22